# Google maps Zoom to Marker Position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Not sure if this is possible but I have set my map up with custom styles and marker and I want to ensure the map shows at this level but with London in view. To do so I centred the map at a different location to my marker. I would like the map to zoom to my location if possible instead of the centre.

```
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng('51.4525368','0.2481994');


        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng('51.4600368','0.0781994'),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scrollwheel:false

        };
```

Also if anybody can tell me why my info window is displaying all funky I would appreciate too.

Comment: what do you mean with "my location"?

Comment: you asked "why my info window is displaying all funky", but didn't provide any information on what you are doing.  It is probably a css issue though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zoom in to marker google.maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054515/zoom-in-to-marker-google-maps)

Comment: Sorry, bit vague and forgot to link. I would like the map zoom function to zoom into my marker mylatlng which is specified as the top var. But as I want the map to display a wider view to include London I have had to set the center to a different Latlng. http://www.liebekuchen.co.uk/talk-to-us/

Answer (score 0):

It has been tough to understand your question but if I got you right, you are trying to fit both center of London and your location on the map without setting a center on some position on the map. If that's correct, then you need `google.maps.LatLngBounds()` to get it done.

```
var bounds= new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var London= new google.maps.LatLng(//London values);
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(//your values);
bounds.extend(London);
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Check if this serves your purpose.

Comment: Also defining 'funky' about your infowindow will help to provide a solution.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the solution I am after. I have tried implementing into my code but it is breaking. Do I need to define the Var i.e declare it globally window.markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); or can it be added to  var mapOptions? Just a bit confused as to where this code needs to be added.

Comment: Funky...yeah sorry. Not sure if you can see on the link but clicking the marker brings up the infowindow but the shadow is displaying incorrectly and there are pixels on the window that are displaying badly.

Comment: Use the above code after defining the map, like after the var map= new google.maps.Map(...);

Comment: Regarding your infowindow, isn't it just the normal infowindow? Did you add any styling to it?

Comment: No styling added to the infowindow just JSON styling for map layers, it seems to be obscuring the links and the shadow is displaying patchy. Tried inspector but can't see any noticeable CSS clashes