# Google Maps zoom to specific marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on my first google map, the purpose of the map is to show various markers in one city but the map should be zoomed into the marker which I set within the code.

So far I have everything working as it should but I can't figure out how to zoom to a specific marker, at the minute the maps centers and fits in all the markers. Below is my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['Elements ll at McConachie, Edmonton', 53.634976,-113.426110],
        ['Creekwood Landing, Edmonton', 53.399758,-113.280340],
        ['Heritage Valley Station, Edmonton', 53.403244,-113.538686],
        ['Walker Lake Gate, Edmonton', 53.420672,-113.421288],
        ['Rutherford Landing, Edmonton', 53.409733,-113.533793],
        ['Vita Estates, Edmonton', 53.644733,-113.462985],
        ['Mactaggart Ridge Gate, Edmonton', 53.433462,-113.571319]
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/elements-logo.png" alt="Elements ll at McConachie" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/> 1060 McConachie Drive NW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/creekwood-logo.png" alt="Creekwood Landing" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/>11803 22 Avenue SW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>'],
         ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/heritage-logo.png" alt="Heritage Valley Station" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/>11803 22 Avenue SW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>'],
         ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/walkerlake-logo.png" alt="WalkerLake Gate" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/>11803 22 Avenue SW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>'],
         ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/rutherford-logo.png" alt="Rutherford Landing" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/>11803 22 Avenue SW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>'],
         ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/vita-logo.png" alt="Vita Estates" />' +
        '<p><strong>Presentation Centre</strong><br/>1060 McConachie Drive NW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>'],
         ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<img src="/map/images/mactarggart--logo.png" alt="Mactaggart Ridge Gate" />' +
        '<p><strong>Sales Centre</strong><br/>11803 22 Avenue SW<br/><a href="#" target="_blank">Directions</a></p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        var iconBase = 'images/';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: iconBase + 'carlisle_icon.png'
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(10);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
    </script>
```

Comment: How do you "set the code" in the code? [example of linkto functionality](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?id=Marker%20One&lat=43.646014&lng=-79.928971&zoom=11&type=m)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions) you must give your map a center location (required). Now which marker you want your map to center on?

Answer (score 5):

Set the correct zoom and pass the marker position as below

```
map.setZoom(17);
map.panTo(currentmarker.position);
```

Further details can be found here [Zoom in to marker google.maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054515/zoom-in-to-marker-google-maps)

Answer (score 3):

To center the map on the third marker, you can do this:

1. push your markers into a global array (gmarkers):

   ```
   for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
     var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
     bounds.extend(position);
     var iconBase = 'images/';
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       map: map,
       title: markers[i][0] /*,
       icon: iconBase + 'carlisle_icon.png' */
     });
     gmarkers.push(marker);
     // Allow each marker to have an info window    
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
           infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
           infoWindow.open(map, marker);
       }
     })(marker, i));

     // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
   }
   ```
2. center on the third marker (gmarkers[2]):

   ```
   var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
     map.setZoom(15);
     map.setCenter(gmarkers[2].getPosition());
     google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
   });
   ```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rb5qt/)

**Note:** both map and the gmarkers array are global variables.

Comment: map.setzoom(15) is working fine but "zoom in" and "zoom out" not working for me. please suggest me.

Comment: That is another question.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.634976, -113.426110));
```