# Google map in mvc from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database, google-maps

1. I need code such that when i click on location name,it show me its
   address with markers in googleMap. i have already store each
   location with its Latitude and longitude in DataBase. Can any one
   please help me that how to do it in ASP.Net MVC. Please help me.
2. My model is this

   ```
         public partial class Location
         {
              public int LocationId { get; set; }
              public string LocationName { get; set; }
              public Nullable<double> Latitude { get; set; }
              public Nullable<double> Longitude { get; set; }
         }
   ```

   My controller

   public class Map Controller : Controller
       {

   ```
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           yellowpagesEntities db = new yellowpagesEntities();
           return View(db.Locations.ToList());
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Search(string Location)
       {

           yellowpagesEntities db = new yellowpagesEntities();
           var result = db.Locations.Where(x => x.LocationName.StartsWith(Location)).ToList();
           return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
   }
   ```

My index view

```
@model IEnumerable<Yellowpage.Models.Location>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
@*jquery file*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var gmarkers = [];
        var map;

        function initialize() {

            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.593684, 78.96288), //India Lat and Lon
                zoom: 2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



        $("#txtSearch").keyup(function () {
            var x = $("#txtSearch").val();

            for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Map")', //"../Map/Search"
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "Location": x }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var table = "<table class='table'>";
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        table += "<tr><td>" + value.LocationName + "</td></tr>";
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            icon: "../pinkball.png",
                            map: map
                        });

                        gmarkers.push(marker);

                    });
                    table += "</table>";
                    $("#myData").html(table);

                    if (x == "") {
                        for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
                            gmarkers[j].setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<table >
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            @Html.TextBox("txtSearch", null, new { @placeholder = "Search A Country" })
            <div id="myData">
                <table class="table">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.LocationName
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:1000px;height:600px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829292/jQuery-Based-Ajax-ASP-NET-MVC-Google-Maps-Web-App

Comment: i study that but when i enter countryName in search it do not show markers on map.

Comment: can you show me your code ?

Comment: Check it now. this is my code

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Check it This is my code.

Comment: are you getting any console errors ?

Comment: yes some console error

Comment: show me that console errors

Comment: (Uncaught TypeError: a(...).live is not a function)  show this error in  (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5 )

Comment: Second error is  Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

Comment: XC=function(a){window.console&&window.console.warn&&window.console.warn("Google Maps API warning: "+a+": https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages")};

Comment: First you have to replace "live" with "on" when creating events  see this link http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Now all the errors are resolove except this one...........Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)          http://pinkball.png

Comment: yes that means the specified image is not found to set the marker icon: "../pinkball.png",

Comment: if you don't want a custom marker then remove that property otherwise set a valid icon path

Comment: Thanks. now its work correctly. But i want that when i enter a specific country name. it zoom that location. where to do it in code and how.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054515/zoom-in-to-marker-google-maps

Comment: where i have to write that code in my code. please help me.

Comment: after  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            icon: "../pinkball.png",
                            map: map
                        });

Comment: But i think before that you need to put a bool field in your model to mark that that location equals with your search condition while other locations satisfies begins with or contains condition

Comment: So using that field we can understand that we location need to zoom