# How to zoom in closely on a marker by spinner onClick?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, android-spinner

I have a map application that show bicycle stops in Tehran.
it looks like this

[image: App screenshot]

what I want to do is that whenever I click on one of the spinner item, it zooms closely on that item's location. like this:
[image: App screenshot]

I tried to make it right but it doesn't work.

**here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LocationListener {
    public Marker marker1;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    Spinner spr_place_list;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageView menu_icon;
    String[] mPlaceType = null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName = null;
    ImageView share_button;
    double mLatitude = 0;
    double mLongitude = 0;

    static final LatLng JAVANMARDAN = new LatLng(35.747394, 51.267577);

    static final LatLng BAKERYHIPERSTAR = new LatLng(35.725623, 51.295175);

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_two);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        menu_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);

        //SHARE BUTTON
        View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareUrl();


            }
        };

        findViewById(R.id.share_button).setOnClickListener(handler);

        // A    rray of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_name);

        // Array of place type names
        // mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceType);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner
        spr_place_list = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_list);
        final List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("جوانمردان 1");
        categories.add("هایپر استار");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        spr_place_list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
        );
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available


            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment

            SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            fragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("بوستان جوانمردان").position(JAVANMARDAN));

                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(JAVANMARDAN, 15));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("بزرگراه شهید باکری - هایپر استار").position(BAKERYHIPERSTAR));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BAKERYHIPERSTAR, 15));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

                }
            });


            spr_place_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                    if (selectedItem.equals("جوانمردان 1")) {


                    }
                }


                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);


        }

    }

    private void shareUrl() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        //TEXT
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "اپلیکیشن دوچرخه سواری");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "؟؟؟؟؟");

        //IMAGE

        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageState() +
                "/share_image.png";

        File imageFileShare = new File(imagePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileShare);

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share link!"));


    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Ex downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        if (selectedItem.equals("جوانمردان 1")) {

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("بزرگراه شهید باکری - هایپر استار").position(BAKERYHIPERSTAR));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BAKERYHIPERSTAR, 21));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(21), 2000, null);


            //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BAKERYHIPERSTAR,20));
            //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(21), 5000, null);
        }
    }


    /**
     * A class, to download Google Places
     */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
//        return true;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your eventListener, try adding

```
map.setZoom(9);
map.panTo(curmarker.position);
```

As mentioned in W3Schools Tutorial - [Google Maps Events](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_events.asp), attach an event handler to a marker that zooms the map when clicked then, with `panTo()`, pan the map back to the marker.

You may try it yourself in W3schools tutorial and solution given in this SO post - [Zoom in to marker google.maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054515/zoom-in-to-marker-google-maps) might be helpful too.

Comment: thanks but it says " cannot resolve setZoom and panTo".