# Apply Zoom In Zoom out feature by clicking dropdown list any value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

current screen is here. i m showing some locations in the map.locations are basically markers ,you can see markers in this picture.what i want to do is,,,[image: current screen is here. i m showing some locations in the map.locations are basically markers ,you can see markers in this picture.what i want to do is,,,]

when i change the dropdownlist value i want to zoom in the chart where i can easily see one of the marker position after clicking some another dropdownlist value like when i click on PG & E the google map will zoom in to the specific marker. i will share my code with you. most importantly i am using kml file to load the map on the screen.
[image: when i change the dropdownlist value i want to zoom in the chart where i can easily see one of the marker position after clicking some another dropdownlist value like when i click on PG & E the google map will zoom in to the specific marker. i will share my code with you.]

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        //   center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'https://sites.google.com/site/kmzmap1/plm/868l_little%20falls-st%20stephens%202%20.kmz?attredirects=0&d=1',
        map: map
    });
}
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

and my html code is .....

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:478px;"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zoom in to marker google.maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054515/zoom-in-to-marker-google-maps)

Comment: i didn't get your  point @gus27

Comment: will you give me a live demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JQuery to achieve this. I will work through an example.

Define a Select box:

```
<select>
 <option >Choose...</option>
  <option value="in">zoom in</option>
  <option value="out">zoom out</option>
</select>
```

We then need to ensure that the map is globally defined so we can access anywyere within the `<script>` aspect of the page

`var map;`

then assign your map to that variable `map = new google...`

We then use jquery to listen to the select box and perform some sort of action:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if(valueSelected == 'in'){
      map.setZoom(17);
    } 
    if(valueSelected == 'out'){
    map.setZoom(4);
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(33.818038, -117.928492));
    }
})
```

- `optionSelected` gets the value of this select box (having multiple you probably be best basing this on ID rather than generic select).
- `valueSelected` is the value of this selected item (in my example in or out).
- we then call what to do; if `in` we increase the zoom in, if `out` we zoom out and pan to a coordinate (this could be a marker).

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2741/